# Angular2 directive usage in template

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have found an recursive object view component that shows an object/array structure as a structured list.
Here is the working component:
https://embed.plnkr.co/Anxv8zImWmD0WzizCSVT/
What i tried was to use the directive in an template that is loaded via templateUrl instead using template.
Here is my not working example:
https://embed.plnkr.co/mHEKcxnUcTk85OSffbCe/

Can you tell me what did I do wrong in my example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app won't start because it's unable to find your template file. In `app.ts`, change:

```
templateUrl: './my-template.html'
```

With:

```
templateUrl: 'src/my-template.html'
```

By the way, if you're just learning Angular, I *strongly* recommend that you work with the latest version. Your example is based on version `2 beta 15` and Angular has changed significantly since then, including many breaking changes.

[Work with this plunkr](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html) instead.  Angular team keeps it up to date with the latest version (currently 2 rc.5)